# Set substract operation

Tags: elixir

I want to do set operation for two tuple item's list and "-" operation not work.

My code is as follows, can it be simplied?

```
iex(6)> b = [{1,0,0},{1,0,1}]
[{1, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 1}]
iex(7)> c = [{1,0,1}]

iex(9)> MapSet.difference(MapSet.new(b),MapSet.new(c)).to_list()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need to use `MapSet` for that, [`--`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#--/2) is enough:

```elixir
iex> [{1,0,0},{1,0,1}] -- [{1,0,1}]
[{1, 0, 0}]
```

For your code above, `.to_list` is tying to access a `:to_list` key on the `MapSet` struct, which does not exist. Elixir does not have methods, you cannot use `data.function()` to call a function, you have to always use the module name (except for `Kernel`, where it can be omitted). The correct syntax is to use a pipe:

```elixir
iex> MapSet.difference(MapSet.new(b),MapSet.new(c)) |> MapSet.to_list()
[{1, 0, 0}]
```

Comment: Please be aware `MapSet.difference/2` and `Kernel.--/2` produce different results. `[1, 1] -- [1] #⇒ [1]`.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin `MapSet` do not allow for duplicates, so it will produce the same output in this case.

Comment: @Hauleth no it won’t exactly because `MapSet` would discard dups and `list` wouldn’t: `[1, 1] -- [1] #⇒ [1]` but `MapSet.difference(MapSet.new([1, 1]),MapSet.new([1])) |> MapSet.to_list() #⇒ []`. For this particular input—yes, but not in general.